# My laptop is unable to run .mkv files properly,any help?

Tags: drivers, video, vlc, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 currently. I use vlc media player as my default! It seems only .mkv files are facing lag issues! I know my device cannot play high resolution file (>1080p) so I always stick with those but it seems vlc is lagging or freezing while playing .mkv files. Is there any solution to this or I just have to stick to the files which are not .mkv?

My device's configuration:
Processor: AMD E1
RAM:4gb(DDR3)
Graphics:Radeon R2